# How does Java encode strings to bytecode?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, byte, java-bytecode-asm

I'm just curious as to how a string Java Assembly code is converted to bytecode?
Say for example the java assembly code said this:

```
print 'Hello World'
```

I know this isn't what Java Assembly actually looks like, it's just to help get my point across. How does Java convert the above code into byte code? For example does the assembler remove the single quotes to leave this:

```
print Hello World
```

And then take the print as the instruction and everything else as the argument when converting to byte code or does it preserve the single quotes? Sorry if my question is hard to understand, if my question is hard to understand I'd be happy to edit it.

Comment: You are way off the mark... there are no quotes involved at all in this. The string is represented in bytecode just as a simple reference. The string's characters are in a separate structure, the constant pool.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for your reply! What does Java do to strings when converting the assembly to byte code? Are the strings converted to numbers or are the strings left alone?

Comment: First of all, I don't know what you even mean by "assembly" since no such thing is involved in the process of compiling Java to .class files. Second, strings are already numbers (what else could they be?) and in the .class file these numbers may be exactly the same as in your .java file, or may be in a different encoding, but that's not a very large difference.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik By "strings are already numbers" do you mean that a string encoded in unicode is just made up of the unicode numbers, for example a = 0061 in unicode. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. The same numbers encode strings in .java and in .class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks again for your reply! I just have 1 more question. So if I open a class file in a hex editor, and in the source file the was the string "a" just on its own. Would I see the hexadecimal value of 0061 or whatever encoding Java uses?

Comment: Yes, you would see it (just checked, apparently it uses UTF-8), along with many other strings, such as names of variables, referenced classes, and so on.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading a book (or attending a course) about compiler technology. It's good that you are curious about how this works, but it's really not something one can explain in a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no bytecodes, per se, involved in the storage of literal constants. The .class file just has a table of these constants, and when the class is loaded they're placed into memory, much like initializing static variables.